# Lotusscript skip element from array?

Tags: lotusscript

I have 3(or more) department. For each department there are email recipient(s). Eg:

Dept A: John, Mary. Dept B: John, Chris. Dept C: John.

The field(text list) is called EmailRecipient in the form Dept. Currently I've managed to send email to each recipient of each department. But I only need to send email to John once only since the content of the email is the same. What I've done currently in my test agent is as following:

```
Dim view As NotesView, doc As NotesDocument
Set view=db.Getview("Department")
Set doc=view.Getfirstdocument()
Do While Not doc Is Nothing
    ForAll x In doc.EmailRecipient
        Set doc=db.Createdocument()
        doc.form="Memo"
        doc.subject="test"
        Call doc.Send(True, x)
    End ForAll
Loop
```

How do I skip John in the next dept's EmailRecipient array if I've already sent email to him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a List.  If you don't know about the List datatype in LotusScript, look up "Working with Lists" in your Domino Designer help database.

Outside of your loops you'll create a list:

```
dim alreadySent List as String
```

Inside your forall, you'll add each name to the list:

```
alreadySent(x) = departmentName
```

And finally you will put your call to doc.Send inside an if statement that checks the list:

```
if isElement(alreadySent(x)) = True then
   ' print "Skipping " + x + " because the message was already to this recipient sent for department " + alreadySent(x) 
   Call doc.send(True,x)
end if
```

*Note that I'm improvising a bit here.  I'm assuming that your Dept form has a field for the name.  I know you haven't actually read it, but it's easy enough for you to add.  You don't really have to do it because you could just as easily have declared 'alreadySent List as Boolean' and assigned alreadySent(x) = True, but by using a String List and assigning the departmentName for each recipient you can track which department you already saw this user in.  I included the commented-out print statement to show how that might be useful.*

Comment: Thanks it work. The only difference is I put the doc.sent() in an 'Else' statement'